# how can I filled with a Xuggle IPacket from RTP Stream

Tags: xuggler

When we decode a file, we can read a file with IContainer and after call container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0, the packet can be filled. But how can I fill with the packet when I only get the H.264 Stream

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the H.264 stream is incoming, and you're wondering how to fill a packet with the data, correct?

In that case, you're doing it correctly. As long as you set up your IContainer to use the URL/Path of your H.264 stream, then container.readNextPacket(packet) will fill the IPacket with a packet of data from the H.264 stream.